# Mule - IOException: Path: exists but isn't a directory

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule-connector

I am using Mule file connector to read a file from shared location. Shared location and my deployment env both are windows based. Mapped the shared location in my Deployment env as J:/ drive and used a directory J:/test.

I can browse this directory from Windows Explorer and also from any browser. But during deployment it's throwing error.

```
 IOException: Path: J:/test exists but isn't a directory
```

Note: Directory permission is Allowed for any user. Shouldn't be a permission issue.

If I use any local directory like C:/test, it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

most likely your issue is due to the security context that the mule runtime is executing. try starting up the runtime under a user vs a windows service account.

Comment: Yes, the exception `Path: <foo> exists but isn't a directory` commonly occurs when the Mule runtime doesn't have sufficient access rights. However, @ray states the access rights were set properly.

Answer (score 0):

You are running your Mule runtime under some ID. This ID on this particular box does not have access to this folder. Provide access to this folder to this ID or use another ID which has such access.

Answer (score 0):

This use case is a common misconception when using the Mule's *File Connector*.

The official documentation for [File Connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/file-connector) states:

> The File connector *only supports working with files on the same **physical system** than the running application*. It doesn’t transfer files remotely over network connections. The only exception is when the operating system maps remote connections to local directories transparently.

In my experience, the File connector doesn't support working with *Windows Network* shared (SMB) nor *NFS* systems.

The solution is to access the data via a network oriented protocol - eg. *SFTP* or *JMS*. Mule contains dedicated connectors for both of them.